# Array of getElementById

Tags: javascript

I am making a table where when you press a button a random cell from the table changes its background color. I need to put variables with `document.GetElementById` in an array but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code below:

```
function setColor(){

        var one = document.GetElementById('t1')
        var two = document.GetElementById('t2')
        var three= document.GetElementById('t3')
            var cells = [];
 cells.push("one");
 cells.push("'two'");
 cells.push("three");

        var valueToUse = cells[Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length)];
     valueToUse.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` not `GetElementById`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding strings in your `cells` array. Use the following:

```
 cells.push(one);
 cells.push(two);
 cells.push(three);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing strings into `cells`, not the elements.

```
function setColor(){

        var one = document.getElementById('t1')
        var two = document.getElementById('t2')
        var three= document.getElementById('t3')
            var cells = [];
        cells.push(one);
        cells.push(two);
        cells.push(three);

        var valueToUse = cells[Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length)];
        valueToUse.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Also as j08691 says, its `getElementById`, not `GetElementById`.

Comment: Fix your `GetElementById`

Comment: yeah same I didn't notice that tnx a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing strings into the cells array, these are completely different objects from the document elements themselves.

```
cells.push(one);
cells.push(two);
cells.push(three);
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
function setColor(){

        var one = document.getElementById('t1')
        var two = document.getElementById('t2')
        var three= document.getElementById('t3')
            var cells = [];
 cells.push(one.value);
 cells.push(two.value);
 cells.push(three.value);

        var valueToUse = cells[Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length)];
     valueToUse.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

You need to push the value to each element instead of a string with the name of it

Comment: Fix your `GetElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the array and use the random number directly to address the element.

BTW, `getElementById` starts with a small letter.

```
function setColor() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1,
        element = document.getElementById('t' + randomNumber);

     element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: tnx that will definetly help make my code look better :P